# How Google Map search functionality trigger on my custom button click in javascript (without autocomplete)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

**How Google Map search functionality trigger on my custom button click  (without autocomplete) search? I have already this code...**.

[This example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete feature.

People can enter geographical searches.

The search box will return a pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

Comment: The question  is a bit illegible.  Can you format the language  for readability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my sample,
I'm using the "Change" event of textbox and "Click" event of button
[image]

```js
var map;
var root;
var geocoder;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'Ha noi, Vietnam'}, function(results, status) {
    root = results[0].geometry.location;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 18,
      center: root,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }); 
    
    
    var center = {latLng: root, style: 'ae', content: 'md'};

     var zoomControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var zoomControl = new ZoomControl(zoomControlDiv, map);

  zoomControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(zoomControlDiv);
    
    
    
   
   });
}
function ZoomControl(controlDiv, map) {
  
  // Creating divs & styles for custom zoom control
  controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

  // Set CSS for the control wrapper
  var controlWrapper = document.createElement('div');

  controlDiv.appendChild(controlWrapper);
  
  // Set CSS for the zoomIn
  var txtAddress = document.createElement('input');
  //zoomInButton.innerHTML = '<br><img src=images/Plus.png title="Zoom In">';
  txtAddress.type="text";
  
  controlWrapper.appendChild(txtAddress);
  
  var bttAddress = document.createElement('input');
  //zoomInButton.innerHTML = '<br><img src=images/Plus.png title="Zoom In">';
  bttAddress.type    = "button";
  bttAddress.value= "Search";
  
  controlWrapper.appendChild(txtAddress);
  controlWrapper.appendChild(bttAddress);
  
  
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(txtAddress, 'change', function() {

geocoder.geocode({'address': txtAddress.value}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location,
     title: txtAddress.value+' '+results[0].geometry.location
            });
   map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
   
   
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
  });
  
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(bttAddress, 'click', function() {

geocoder.geocode({'address': txtAddress.value}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location,
     title: txtAddress.value+' '+results[0].geometry.location
            });
   map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
   
   
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
  });
  
    
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<title>Google Maps API</title>

<style type="text/css">
#map {
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="init_map.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="map">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```